# implement a booking lock for users in a scheduling app

Tags: sql, ruby, web-applications, hanami

I've built a scheduling web app where users can book a conference for a given date and time slot on that date.

Now I need to implement a booking lock, which means that the admin can apply this lock and users can no longer book from that time on.

My current design includes a model booking_lock that only has one attribute of "status" with values of "On" and "Off".

The model would have only one record in the database at any given time as its sole responsibility would be to provide the data to check if booking has been locked.

---------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

This is not meant to lock individual records (conferences). To do this I use the attribute of user_id. If that is 0, then the conference is available for booking.

What I want to do now is disable (lock) the booking entirely before the user hits the database.

For example:

When a user logs on they see a notification saying the booking is locked. Also, they wouldn't see a respective button to book a conference and if by chance they would navigate to the respective URL they would be redirected to home page with the same notice as above. I've got all this covered.

But I need a general switch to be turned on and off and be the basis for this kind of check. Hence the booking_lock model.

Note: I use hanami-model.

---------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a better way of implementing such a lock?
2. How to ensure there is only one record in the db for such lock?

Comment: Do you want to apply the lock application-wide or just for specific users ?

Comment: For a specific user class.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand: a specific user id or a specific user class ?

Comment: For a specific user class. Concrete example: it's about parent/teacher conferences. After the lock has been applied, parents can no longer book conferences, while teachers can still book or cancel bookings for parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Is there a better way of implementing such a lock?

It seems that your requirement is to have an **application-wide setting**, which is best done with

- An environment variable
- A value stored in database

#### Environment variables:

- pros: system already in place, simple usage, can easily be configured statically and changed dynamically
- cons: might be difficult to maintain with a multi-tenant architecture (multiple servers running the same app)

#### DB persistence

- pros: scales easily with a multi-tenant architecture
- cons: can seem a bit of an overkill for one setting BUT can easily be abstracted into a Key/Value store for multiple settings.

#### Example:

Create an AppSettings model with two columns: key & value.

Create and save an AppSetting with key "lock_booking_for_parents" and change the value through an admin interface.

Access this AppSetting throughout the app to know if you should lock booking or not.

Also, if you are worried about querying your database everytime you need to know if booking is enabled/disabled, you can easily implement caching.

## 2. How to ensure there is only one record in the db for such lock?

#### Environment variable

Not applicable

#### DB persistence

You can create a helper class to access your settings with default behavior, and use `first_or_create` method to ensure the record is unique.

```
class AppSettingsHelper

    def self.booking_enable?
      app_setting_record = AppSettings.find_by_key("lock_booking_for_parents")
      if app_setting_record 
        return app_setting_record.value
      else 
        ## default behavior of your app when no record has been created yet
        return true
      end
    end
    
    def self.enable_booking
      AppSettings.where(:key => "lock_booking_for_parents").first_or_create({value: false})
    end
    
    def self.disable_booking
      AppSettings.where(:key => "lock_booking_for_parents").first_or_create({value: true})
    end  
end
```

Comment: I was going for the DB approach, haven't even thought of the possibility of ENV variable. One more question: what's the benefit of your key/value option to my one column with values of On and Off?

Comment: One benefit is that next time you need another similar setting, you can just add one more row to your AppSettings table.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution!

Comment: I've just implemented the DB persistence option with key/value and works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score -1):

You could try the [ActiveRecord pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) method, or something like it. Set a field on your record that indicates a lock and try it:

```
booking_lock = UUID.new # Or any sufficiently unique string
Booking.update_all({ id: @booking.id, booking_lock: booking_lock }, { booking_lock: nil })
booked = Booking.find_by(id: @booking.id, booking_lock: booking_lock)
```

If you get the record back you successfully locked it. If not you need to try again with a different booking, it got nabbed before you could claim it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see my edit above, I might not have elaborated clearly before.